# How to combine each three rows into single column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
NOOfDays   DISTRInutorID
-------------------------    
1           abcd    
1           cdef    
2           DFSDF    
2           SFSDD    
2           SDFSD    
2           WAOYWAR    
7           WEFIWE    
7           WEOFYWE    
7           WFYREU
```

The above is one of my sample tables, I want to combine each two rows based on NOOfDays.

Expected output:

```
NOOfDays         DiSTRInutorID
------------------------------
1                 abcd, cdef              
2                 DFSDF, SFSDD       
2                 SDFSD, WAOYWAR            
7                 WEFIWE, WEOFYWE         
7                 WFYREU
```

Comment: Why are you using unsupported versions of SQL Server?

Comment: Existing old projects, not upgraded

Answer (score 2):

In ancient versions of SQL Server, the logic looks like:

```
select n.NOOfDays,
       stuff( (select ',' + t2.DISTRInutorID
               from t t2
               where t2.NOOfDays = n.NOOfDays
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as list
from (select distinct NOOfDays from t) n;
```

EDIT:

I misunderstood the original question.  This is what you are looking for:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     )
select NOOfDays,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then min(DISTRInutorID)
             else max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then DISTRInutorID end) + ',' + max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then DISTRInutorID end)
        end) as list
from cte
group by NOOfDays, floor(seqnum / 2);
```

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  This arbitrarily pairs rows where the first column is the same, but there is no guarantee that these are adjacent -- for the simple reason that "adjacent" is not defined.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f99df77cba290b5c577ce8aeba7f01b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Its combining all DISTRInutorID's based on NOOfDays, but i want to comine each two or three rows based on NOOfDays.

Comment: @killisuman . . . This should do what you want.  There was a typo, but it should have resulted in a syntax error rather than the results you describe.